# I want to check if a string is abecedarian

Tags: python, string

I want to check if a string is abecedarian (in alphabetical order).

```
def is_abecdarian(s):
    index = 0
    while index < len(s)-1:
        if s[index + 1] > s[index]:
            return True
        index += 1
    return False
print(is_abecdarian('babcd'))
```

If I switch my False and True around and switch the greater than to less than it works. What I do not understand is 'a' is not greater than 'b', yet when I run the above code it returns True.

Comment: Your loop is checking for any position where the alphabetical order condition fails. If at any step, the next character is alphabetically less than the previous character, the string is not in order, so the function should return false. After the loop has checked every position, if it hasn't at any point returned false, then it must be all in order, so the function should return true.

Comment: This code makes no sense.  You enter the loop, then on the first iteration you check if the first two elements are in order, and if they are, you immediately return `True` without even looking at the rest of the string.  Why?  This functions checks if *any* pair of consecutive characters in the string is in order, and if so, it returns `True`.  It only returns `False` if every consecutive pair is out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your loop is written, it will return True if any pair of characters is ordered. It only returns False if all pairs fail. The first pair `ba` fails the if check, but the second pair `ab` passes and the function returns True.

This isn't right, because if you think about it, you can't know that a string is abecedarian until you've examined *all* of the characters. You should only be returning True when you're done with the loop. Conversely, as soon as you find a pair of characters that's out of order, it is safe to return False.

That's why flipping the booleans and the `<` operation works.

Comment: That makes prefect sense - we must eliminate all possibilities before we come to a conclusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `return True` statement exits the function, so right now it runs until there are two letters that are in a correct order and then exits.

Comment: I'm assuming the {return False} does not exit the function?

Comment: The function doesn't reach it. It exits the moment it finds a correct pair of letters

Comment: It does reach it if *every* index position fails the `if` statement.

Comment: You're right, but I'm referring to this specific case

Answer (score 0):

You need to return False only if next character is `<` than current.
If there were no such an occurrence during all the loop then return True.

Here is correct function:

```
def is_abecdarian(s):
    index = 0
    while index < len(s)-1:
        if s[index + 1] < s[index]:
            return False
        index += 1
    return True

print(is_abecdarian('babcd'))
print(is_abecdarian('abcz'))
```

Comment: Though a `for` statement is the idiomatic way to loop over a monotonically increasing index.

Answer (score 0):

Why it's not working has already been explained, so, only to add to what has been explained:

```
def is_abecdarian(s):
    return all(s[i] < s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1))

print(is_abecdarian('babcd'))
print(is_abecdarian('ejmpq'))
```

Where

- `all(argument)` returns `True` only if all boolean in the argument are True;
- `s[i] < s[i+1]` is a comparison between the i-th element of `s` to the next one.
- `s[i] < s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1)` makes the comparison for all pairs of consecutive elements of `s`.

Comment: Can you explain why OP's code isn't working, other than they're not doing it your way?

Comment: Well this was only an addition, as it has already been explained. I will add this to my answer, as well as explanations. I do think it brings something because it's easier to read and hence leads less to errors that are complicated to understand.

Comment: Shorter and perhaps clearer: `all(a < b for a, b in zip(s, s[1:])`

Comment: `izip` and `islice` would be more efficient too.